# Cut string from last dash

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So I have a column as below:

```
String
PPS1PS
PPS1PS - INVEM
PPS1PS - INVEM - ABCD
```

What I need to do is cut from the last "-" in the string and show the final characters.  So the above should turn into:

```
String
PPS1PS
INVEM
ABCD
```

Struggling in my head how to do this.  So far I have the following:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(50)
SET @String = 'PPS1PS - INVEM - ABCDE'

select @String

select LTRIM(RIGHT(@String,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@String))))
```

Which is fine for the last two in the column.  But what happens if there is no "-", how can I cater for that?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for one of those strings to contain a hyphen? For example: `PPS1PS - INVEM - CD-ROM`, and therefore you would want `CD-ROM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your query just using `case` statement:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @String like '%-%'
             THEN LTRIM(RIGHT(@String, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@String))))
             ELSE @String
        END)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
SELECT Ltrim(Parsename(Replace('PPS1PS - INVEM - ABCD', '-', '.'), 1)) 

SELECT Ltrim(Parsename(Replace(YourColumn, '-', '.'), 1)) 
From   YourTable
```

you can add `Rtrim` if necessary.

NOTE : it won't work if you have more than 3 `-` in your string.
See details of `parsename` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188006.aspx).

Comment: I would have used this but I was just concerned with if PARSENAME would change in the future with the way it works.  Prefer to use standard functions to achieve this.  Thanks for your reply though.  Good answer.